# Начались выборы модераторов – 2020

Tags: обсуждение

На нашем сайте **22 июня** начался этап выдвижения кандидатур на [специальных выборах в модераторы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/election/2). Мы надеемся, что удастся увеличить текущую команду сайта.

Чтобы ознакомиться со всеми деталями, пожалуйста, посетите страницу [на Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections).

Этапы:

- Начиная с 22 июня участники могут [выдвинуть свою кандидатуру](https://rus.stackexchange.com/election/2). Также участники с помощью Меты могут задавать вопросы кандидатам. (Помечайте соответствующие вопросы метками [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).)
- 29 июня, если будут выдвинуты хотя бы две кандидатуры, начнется голосование. В противном случае мы автоматически признаем имеющиеся кандидатуры победителями. (Есть небольшая вероятность того, что [нам придётся принудительно снять кандидатуру](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- Если выборы всё-таки состоятся, то результаты будут объявлены 7 июля.

(Текущим модераторам не требуется предпринимать никаких действий.)

Пожалуйста, если у вас есть вопросы, задайте их ниже.

---

Русский язык will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://rus.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **June 22** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on June 22, users can [nominate themselves](https://rus.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) and [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) tags.)
- On June 29, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year)).
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on July 7.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The nomination period for the 2020 election on Russian Language has been extended for a week so that we can have nominations. We need at least one nominee to proceed.

Please take this time to think about whether you're interested in stepping up to support this site as a moderator or - if you know of someone who would be a great moderator here - feel free to encourage them to nominate. Sometimes people don't realize how good a fit they'd be.

The schedule now is:

- July 6th: Nomination ends and voting begins
- July 14th: Voting ends and results are announced

If we do not manage to get candidates by the 6th, this will have to be considered a failed election - in which case we'll discuss with the community what might've happened and when to set up a new one, then try again. Too many consecutive failed elections can make a site up for closure.